# Polygon from Transparent pixels in pascal

Tags: pascal

For hidden object game collision detection,the  following code using zengl
  generates points around the edges of a texture(for design time):

```pascal
tex_GetData(txtr, myData );
for h:=0 to txtr.Height-1 do
begin
    for w:=0 to txtr.Width-1  do
    begin
        if  (PByte(Ptr(myData) + w* 4 + h * realWidth * 4 +3)^>50)and (PByte(Ptr(myData) + w* 4 + h * realWidth * 4 +3)^<150) then
        begin
            inc(counter);
            if counter mod (cn)=0 then
                if cntr<>100 then
                    begin
                    inc(cntr);
                    // setlength(points,(cntr+1));

                    points[cntr].X:=w;

                    points[cntr].y:=w;

                    end ;
```

The problem is about  making a polygon from the given points. The polygon is drwan in the wrong  way.
Now trying to detect first pixels all along each edge by iterating through
width(0 to width)and each time the width increase by one height will iterate from top(=0)until hits first none transparent pexil and will reset to zero when the width will increase by one until scanning the top region.
loops do not work well here:

```pascal
//Top
w:=1;
h:=1;

for w:=0 to texture.Width-1 do
    while(h<txtr.Height-2)do
    begin  

        if  (PByte(Ptr(myData) + w* 4 + h * realWidth * 4 +3)^)=255 then
        begin
            inc(h);

            inc(cntr);
            setlength(points,(cntr+1));
            points[cntr].X:=w;

            points[cntr].y:=h;
            continue;
        end;

        break;


    end ;
```

But it stops half way.
My desire is to make the iteratation through the array of points that draw a polygon lines to take the closest shape :

```pascal
for i:=1 to length(points)-1 do
    begin
        pr2d_Line(points[i].X,points[i].y,points[i+1].X,points[i+1].y,$FF0000,255);
    End;
```

I hope to see a example for the correct looping.

*Update*

```
  if  (PByte(Ptr(myData) + w* 4 + h * realWidth * 4 +3)^)=255 then
```

*The above line is only to detect none transparent pixels in pbytearray and it works (if pixel[w,h] is not transparent then).
Just looking for the first none transparent pixel in an image by scanning every pixel in it by rotating its bounds for example:
scan top from right to left, scan Right from top to bottom, scan bottom from right to left, and finally scan left from bottom to top.
Not sure if that is called vector, but will generate one array of points called with one loop and if its points are connected the result will be a polygon takes the same shape of the raster.*

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's currently very difficult to read.